# Can I auto generate an objects required name field without Enterprise edition workflows?

Tags: workflow, opportunity, automation, create-records

I'm using the default SF opportunity object and want to auto-generate the value for the name field.

Everything I've read about this says "yes its simple when you use workflows and create an on create rule".   Yet I am using a Pro SF account, not an enterprise one.  We have a "Developer Pro" license but no enterprise access so from what I've seen I can't create workflows.

Is what I want to do possible somehow without enterprise access?

Comment: Are you looking to do this so users don't need to set a value for the Name field prior to saving or are you requiring this for tracking/standardization purposes?

Comment: Hi @zainogj - to answer your question both.  Ideally they wouldn't need to enter content and the field would be hidden but its for standardisation purposes as well as streamlining the amount of user input required to absolute minimum.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned below, workflow rules will only fire after the record is saved. Therefore you would lose the "streamlining the amount of user input required" portion of your requirement. I would strongly advise looking into the URL Hack solution mentioned as the sets the value for the user. The only down side is, it may be difficult to have a formula create the auto-number for you - but I've never tried that. Also mentioned below, it appears workflow rules are available in PRO for additional cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think workflow rules would really accomplish what you want either. If you are ok with the user setting any value which upon save has the system overwrite that value to set the auto-generated number for them; workflows would work for you. The problem you won't be able to overcome is the name field is required to save, which means someone/something needs to set that value before a users clicks Save. As you mentioned, workflow rules are not supported in [professional edition](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h06dAAA) without paying a fee; here is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrNvAAK) as well.

---

If you want a solution where a user creates a new opportunity and the name is set for them in the edit screen allowing them to save without ever having to touch the name field, there are three solutions I can think of:
1) [URL Hack](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/); 2) [Publisher Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm); 3) build your own interface with visualforce or APIs and set the value in javascript or a controller before the page loads.

---

### [URL Hack](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/)

This solution would consist of building your own button and replacing the existing "New Opportunity" button in Salesforce. The URL used in the button would set the identified parameter which passes it into the front end for the user to still edit if need be, but never have to touch it to save the record. I don't believe this would support a formula for you though - so an auto-generate number might be hard. As mentioned this would solve the issue of requiring users to set the name field before saving.

### [Publisher Action](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm)

This solution would add an action (more or less a button) to the feed view for your users. If they don't use feed view, this is not a viable option. This solution allows you to set values for fields before they save the record. Again, you could default the name to your desired value - not sure if this works well with setting an auto-generate number which would require a formula.

### Build your own Interface

I'm assuming this is not a viable option for you, but just wanted to mention it as a solution in general. This would require HTML, Visualforce, JavaScript, and/or Lightning development. You would pass the value into the field when the page loads using some javascript.